# Create dataobject in c# to hold values from a table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Read Edit 2 First please.

I have 3 tables in MySQL. Users, Games, UsersGames.

```
    userId int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment Primary key,
    userName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    emailAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

In this instance lets use this Users table.

I would like to create a DataObject Users that will hold the information that I have stored in my database.

I am not too sure how to go about creating the DataObject since I will be calling the DataObjects throughout my program. I am currently trying to get them to work for the login page.

In my c# Users.cs all I have is this...

```
    public String usersId { get; set; }
    public String userName { get; set; }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public String emailAddress { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
```

I am a bit at a loss from here as to how I should get the fields from the database. Would it be done with sql commands and queries?? I am at a loss.

EDIT 1: I have read more about the Direct Database access and I have gotten a decent amount further. But Now I come to a more specific question.

In my Login.aspx.cs page, I am passing through 6 values to the user table, which is listed above, and when I try to execute the query in the try catch, it goes right to the catch. I will post the code below.

```
    if(txtNewPass.Text.Equals(txtVerifyNewPass.Text))
            {
                MySqlConnection dbcon;
                string cstr = "Server=localhost;User ID=root; Password=; Database=finalgame;";



                dbcon = new MySqlConnection(cstr);
                dbcon.Open();
                string inse = "insert into users (userName, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password) values(@username, @firstname, @lastname, @emailadd, @password) ";
                MySqlCommand insertuser = new MySqlCommand(inse, dbcon);
                insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtNewUserName.Text);
                insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", txtFirstName.Text);
                insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLastName.Text);
                insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailadd", txtEmail.Text);
                insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtNewPass.Text);



                try
                {
                    insertuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dbcon.Close();
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("<b>something really bad happened.....Please try again</b> ");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //error incorrect pass
                Console.WriteLine("the passwords do not match");
            }
```

it all seems to work fine until i get to insertuser.ExecuteNonQuery thats when it goes right to the catch. I did just notice that the lastInsertedId is -1, I do no know if that is something significant but it seems worth posting.

Do I need to pass in a blank parameter for the auto_incremented id??

EDIT 2: !!! I looked back and realized I had some typoes, sorry for the extra edit. It all works great now. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Entity Framework for God's sake! And I'm saying this as an atheist.

Comment: Or another data access pattern. Point is, your best bet is to read some tutorials on ways to retrieve data from a db.  There are thousands to choose from :).  Once you pick one and you start implementing it, come back and ask a specific question if/when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options really, direct database access or an ORM as Brian mentioned.

Direct database access appears to be relatively straight forward, you add your .Net adapter for MySQL, connect to your database and execute your statements. However you need to ensure you are properly handling connections (open, close), prepared statements etc.

Direct database access is an option if

- You're interested in learning the nuts and bolts before moving to an ORM
- You're required to use direct access (for whatever reason )

Using an ORM can simplify things greatly. I've used EntityFramework with MySQL with minimal issues.

An ORM is an option if

- You are required to use it (for whatever reason)
- You've done direct access and want to try an ORM

One thing that ORM's do is take a relational model and convert it into a class structure. This will allow you to access your database using object notation like `db.userName = "Bob Lablaw";` and then persist your change with a call to `SaveChanges();`

For instance I use the following to persist package information into a MySQL database:

```
  var insert = new packageinfo
                             {
                                 OrderNumber = orderNum,
                                 PackageType = packageType,
                                 ShipCarrier = shipCarrier,
                                 ShipService = shipService,
                                 TrackingNumber = trackingNumber,
                                 ShipFromAddress = shipFromAddress1,
                                 ShipFromAddress2 = shipFromAddress2,
                                 ShipFromCity = shipFromCity,
                                 ShipFromState = shipFromState,
                                 ShipFromZipCode = shipFromZip,
                                 ShipFromName = shipFromName,
                                 ShipDate = shipDate
                             };
            entity.packageinfoes.AddObject(insert);
            entity.SaveChanges();
```

That all said, I highly recommend starting with direct database and then moving to an ORM. 
Three tables is not a lot to manage with direct db access and it will only help you appreciate what an ORM provides. Besides you'll learn some valuable skills along the way.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, I will try Direct Database access. And I'll post back here more specific answers about Direct Database access if I came across some trouble and cant find any other answers elsewhere. Thanks for the reply and guidance.

Comment: @user2635650 No problem, I hope it helps. The community is here to help you so feel free to post a question at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) tool like NHibernate, etc.  I don't know what specifically supports MySql.  I think Telerik OpenAccess, and maybe Entity Framework does.  These frameworks do a lot of that heavy lifting for you, so you don't have to write that code yourself.  Each ORM has benefits and drawbacks, and should be thoroughly researched before choosing one.